# Rollback and roll-forward except one transaction with MySQL and InnoDB

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, innodb, amazon-rds

I currently use InnoDB transactions to manage the effect of any single webpage request. One request per transaction. This works well if the request fails I can just ignore it.

As a relative newbie to MySQL administration, I remain worried that something I write into my PHP code will do something bad to my database. DELETE FROM or UPDATE without a where statement or something as an extreme example. The idea of the transactions is that when I inevitably notice what happened later, after the bad transaction is committed, I should be able to rollback the mistake.

However, the database is used heavily, so its likely that other transactions will come in between when I commit the bad transaction and when I notice it and go to act on it. But all the documentation I have seen on transactions, and the AWS restore-to-point-in-time, only allow you "go back" to before a transaction is committed.

So, how do I recover or "roll-forward" the transactions that came in after my bad one? They are in the InnoDB log, so should I be able to apply the later transactions again, just skipping the one bad one? My software interfaces with an external credit card processor, so just losing those later transactions isn't an option.

I have a hard time imagining its impossible, but I can't find any way to "roll-forward". Is this possible? Is it something you have to write into the database structure itself, like keeping a history table with triggers and using a history record to update after rolling back?

Confused.

Comment: You don't seem to understand the concepts of transactions: You can't rollback after a transaction has been committed... transactions aren't a fix for bad code, they're a method for ensuring that your database remains consistent in the event of a failure, not a valid SQL update that you didn't want to do

Comment: Transactions can't help you with this - backups can though.

Comment: These are fair. The transactions do create a record, though. If I restore a backup can I replay certain transactions from the transaction log?